# JSONObject shows escape characters

Tags: java, json, string, escaping

I have a manual json object that i created and I use escape characters for one of the fields. I see escape strings whenever i print my jsonobject, is there a way to remove them? I'm just worried that the client will get the json object with the escaped strings when i send this over through the server.

```
        String car_parameters = "{\"property_name\":\"car_id\",\"traceKey\":\"account_id,accountName,car_id\"}";
        System.out.println("car params"+car_parameters);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("message", car_parameters);
        System.out.println("one"+jsonObject);
        System.out.println("two"+payload);
```

These are the outputs respectively, i tried converting json object to string but that did not make a difference.I'd expect to see json object's fields without escape characters like when i print out just the string.

```
car params{"property_name":"car_id","traceKey":"account_id,accountName,car_id"}
one{"message":"{\"property_name\":\"car_id\",\"traceKey\":\"account_id,accountName,car_id\"}"}
two{"message":"{\"property_name\":\"car_id\",\"traceKey\":\"account_id,accountName,car_id\"}"}
```

Comment: That is the correct output. You're putting a string in a JSONObject. If you want to store a JSON object inside a JSON object, parse the string into a JSON object, then `put` that.

Answer (score 1):

The escape character is caused by Java syntax. Java does not allow

```
String car_parameters = "{"property_name":"car_id","traceKey":"account_id,accountName,car_id"}"
```

is converted automatically.

You can turn it into an object, as shown below

```
System.out.println("toString"+JSONObject.parse(car_parameters));
```

output：

```
Object:{"traceKey":"account_id,accountName,car_id","property_name":"car_id"}
```

in addition：
If you send it to the client, it will also be {"message": "{property_ name":"car_ id","traceKey":"account_ id,accountName,car_ id"}"}

\It will become a part of the string, so the front end needs to handle it, but the transfer in Java does not affect the use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. please consider what artifact you need.(My favorite is ObjectMapper.)
If you need generate from string, it is simple.
Maybe there is a lot of harsh way but I think it is not necessary now.
Remember that A first sample need new artifact as below in your `pom.xml`

```xml
<!-- for the JSONParser -->
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
  public void JSonTest() throws JSONException, ParseException {
    String car_parameters = "{\"property_name\":\"car_id\",\"traceKey\":\"account_id,accountName,car_id\"}";
    System.out.println("car params"+car_parameters);

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    Object myObject = jsonParser.parse(car_parameters);
    System.out.println("One" + myObject);

    // Put it separate.
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("property_name", "car_id");
    jsonObject.put("traceKey", "account_id,accountName,car_id");
    System.out.println("Two"+jsonObject);

    jsonObject.remove("property_name");
    jsonObject.remove("traceKey");

    // Put it a map first.
    HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    myMap.put("property_name", "car_id");
    myMap.put("traceKey", "account_id,accountName,car_id");
    jsonObject.put("message", myMap);
    System.out.println("Three"+jsonObject);
  }
```

And Here is output,

```
car params{"property_name":"car_id","traceKey":"account_id,accountName,car_id"}
One{"traceKey":"account_id,accountName,car_id","property_name":"car_id"}
Two{"traceKey":"account_id,accountName,car_id","property_name":"car_id"}
Three{"message":"{traceKey=account_id,accountName,car_id, property_name=car_id}"}
```